# Inconsistency between object explorer and available database dropdown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I am working with SQL Server 2008R2.  I am able to see a database in the "available database" drop down, but not in the object explorer. I am able to query it, for example   `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`  is able to run within the database.

Has anyone seen this before?  I have tried right clicking on the SQL server within object explorer, and hitting refresh, but I am not seeing the database within the object explorer.  It happens to be the "distribution database" as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/ihpublishercolumnindexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

Is that something that ever shows up in the object explorer?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a Filter enabled on Object Explorer?  Look for the little filter icon at the top. Open that, see if there is any text in the Value column.  You can click Clear Filter.

Comment: @ConradS. Filter is grayed out.  At first I thought the table was dropped/deleted....but that doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: Be sure your have "Databases" selected.  If you have one of the databases selected, then the filter icon will be grayed out.  I'll post screenshots to an answer (can't post screenshots in a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(follow-up from my comment to the OP)

This is what you should see:

[image]

Filter icon is grayed out because "Databases" is not selected.

[image]